# Scons compilation errors in IoTivity project on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, scons, iotivity

[image]

I am trying to build IoTivity project in Ubuntu 15.04. I followed the steps mentioned in "https://www.iotivity.org/documentation/linux/getting-started" and when I gave the command "scons" I am getting the compilation errors.

Comment: The answer below gave some good advice, which is that we need errors in text format, not trapped in bitmap images. If you can repair this, that would be great, but I appreciate that since it is a few years old, that is probably not possible. Note that questions can be put on hold for this reason, since we believe they are missing an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to build the software on with a version of GCC and/or Ubuntu not supported by the project?

From their https://www.iotivity.org/documentation/linux/getting-started page it lists Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and GCC 4.6.1.

From the errors you're getting I'd lean more towards being a newer version of GCC than the code supports.

That said I'd recommend sending your problem along to their mailing list(s): 
http://lists.iotivity.org/mailman/listinfo

Also paste the actual text of the error and not a screen shot would be more useful.